# What is the origin of the appellation "Paternoster Gang"?

Tags: doctor-who

Vastra, Jenny, and Strax are referred to as "The Paternoster Gang". How did the group acquire that appellation? I've only seen the name referenced in places like this site or wikis, but don't ever recall mention of the name in the TV show. Did I miss it? Does it only occur in a webisode, extended universe novel, or such? (I've only watched the TV show proper, not watched/read any other media built around the Whoniverse)

Comment: FYI - "Pater Noster" is Latin for "Our Father", ie "Pater Noster qui es in coellis" = "Our Father who art in heaven". This may be a little light sci-fi sacrilege in that the Doctor is the intended father.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive in light of the information from the Doctor Who magazine. Is there anything else you'd like to see addressed before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 4):

In-Universe, it was because the group is headquartered in Vastra's building, Paternoster House. There's no special indication that she named the property herself.

Out of universe (according to an article in the Doctor Who Magazine) the name derives, somewhat circularly from a [BBC reference book article](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Paternoster_Gang) about the group:

> Steven Moffat derived the name Paternoster Gang from The Brilliant Book 2012 where Clayton Hickman referred to their base as Paternoster Row. (DWM 480)

Comment: Actually Paternoster Square is next to st Pauls and replaces Paternoster Row.

I want to see Strax to come to present day London and  come face to face with the tourists and their selfie sticks